# Convert this String to a List in Python

Tags: python, string, list

I'm new to Python and I try to convert following txt to two lists, splitting Country from Capital.

```
Afghanistan | Kabul
Albania | Tirana
Algeria | Algiers
...
```

I tried:

```
with open("/FILE.txt") as f:
    lines = f.read().split("| ")
```

Comment: `lines = [line.split(' | ') for line in f.readlines()]`

Comment: @sahasrara62 no need for `.readlines()` that is pretty much a method that is redundant and mostly around because of all the old code that used it but new code should probably never use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading the entire file into one big string, then splitting that on the separator. The result will look something like

```
lines = ['Afghanistan', 'Kabul\nAlbania', 'Tirana\nAlgeria', 'Algiers']
```

If you want to split the file into lines, the `splitlines` function does that.

```
with open("/FILE.txt") as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
```

But if you want to split that one list into two lists, perhaps try something like

```
countries = []
capitals = []
with open("/FILE.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        country, capital = line.rstrip("\n").split(" | ")
        countries.append(country)
        capitals.append(capital)
```

A better solution still might be to read the values into a dictionary.

```
capital = {}
with open("/FILE.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        country, city = line.rstrip("\n").split(" | ")
        capital[country] = city
```

As an aside, you almost certainly should not have a data file in the root directory of your OS. This location is reserved for administrative files (or really, in practical terms, just the first level of the directory tree hierarchy).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string like string="Kabul Albania" so use Split

```
a="Kabul Albania"
print(a.split(" ")) #OUTPUT WILL BE ['Kabul', 'Albania']
```

Comment: This does not match the format of the OP’s source data.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This should work,
you had the first part right just need to add the result to two different list

```
country = []
capitals = []
with open("FILE.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        result = line.strip().split("|")
        country.append(result[0].strip())
        capitals.append(result[1].strip())

print(country)
print(capitals)
```